# Unable to connect to Internet on Desktop via Ethernet

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, ethernet

Desktop computer it's not connecting to internet via Ethernet. It shows the loading connection animation on the top panel but it never connects, it just keeps loading...
The network card is NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet

Any fixes for this problem?﻿

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Post your `sudo lshw -c network` `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 0):

check your router.
on my system (amd dual core 64 bit, running Ubuntu 14.04) when that happens my router is flagging an attempt to sign on. at that moment if i go push the allow button on the router (linksys wifi) then it resolves.